# Year over Year difference and selecting maximum row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe given as below:

```
ID YEAR     NPS
500 2020     0
500 2021     0
500 2022     0
501 2020    32      
501 2021    52      
501 2022    99      
503 2021    1       
503 2022    4       
504 2020    45      
504 2021    55      
504 2022    50
```

I have to calculate year over year difference as given below:

```
ID      YEAR    NPS  nps_gain_yoy
500     2020     0      0
500     2021     0      0
500     2022     0      0
501     2020    32      0
501     2021    52      20
501     2022    99      47
503     2021    1       0
503     2022    4       3
504     2020    45      0
504     2021    55      10
504     2022    50      -5
```

In above output for starting year 2020 or first occurance of Id nps_gain_yoy needs to be zero then for 2021 nps_gain_yoy is difference between nps of 2021 and 2020 i.e 52-32 = 20 as shown in output for ID 501 for year 2021 and so on.
After this I need to pick the maximum difference or maximum nps_gain_yoy for each ID as given in below output:

```
ID  YEAR    NPS NPS_gain_yoy
501 2022     0    0
501 2022    99   47
503 2022    4    3
504 2021    55   10
```

Here 47 is the maximum nps gain for ID 501 in year 2022 similarly 3 for ID 503 and 4 for Id 504.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If years are consecutive per `ID` first use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','YEAR'])

df['nps_gain_yoy'] = df.groupby('ID')['NPS'].diff().fillna(0)
print (df)
     ID  YEAR  NPS  nps_gain_yoy
0   500  2020    0           0.0
1   500  2021    0           0.0
2   500  2022    0           0.0
3   501  2020   32           0.0
4   501  2021   52          20.0
5   501  2022   99          47.0
6   503  2021    1           0.0
7   503  2022    4           3.0
8   504  2020   45           0.0
9   504  2021   55          10.0
10  504  2022   50          -5.0
```

And then [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.iloc[::-1].groupby('ID')['nps_gain_yoy'].idxmax()]
#alternative solution
#df1 = df.sort_values(['ID','nps_gain_yoy']).drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
print (df1)
    ID  YEAR  NPS  nps_gain_yoy
2  500  2022    0           0.0
5  501  2022   99          47.0
7  503  2022    4           3.0
9  504  2021   55          10.0
```

Comment: For each Id for starting year 2020 I need nps_gain_yoy as zero but I'm getting values other than zero for starting year 2020 can you please check

Comment: @Python_help - `In above output for starting year 2020 or first occurance of Id nps_gain_yoy needs to be zero` - It is different?

Comment: sorry I sorted dataframe in different order and applied your function so it was giving wrong result when I applied on correct solution is working fine. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I modified data by adding ID 500 your solution is giving year as 2020 in final output but I needed 2022 in such cases can you please modify your code

Comment: @Python_help - first part has 3 times 2020, second part edit has 2020, 2021,2022, what is correct?

Comment: modified now please check

Comment: actually your solution is giving year as 2020 in final output but I needed 2022 for cases such as Id 500

Comment: @Python_help - you are right, answer was edited. Added `.iloc[::-1]` for swap rows for test first maximal year row